# result of battery drain

Tags: renault, battery-drain, scenic

done a parasitic test on battery(new) showed up as 1.74 amps,removed fuses 1 by 1 and found that the 20amp fuse for the coupe console when removed dropped the amps to 0.49, i have a 56 renault scenic mk 2,and the coupe console seems to be the instrument panel and dashboard as when this fuse is out there is no display,was wondering if anyone has any idea if the the drain is normal on this type of vehicle(digital instrument panel)or if not any ideas as to how i can check what the problem may be.dan farrell

Comment: Consider saying "late 2006" instead of "56", as people outside UK won't know what "56" means. This is not a UK-only site!

Comment: When you do the current test be sure to leave the meter in place 5 10 minure to be sure you aren't reading some device start up current

Comment: In short, you need wiring diagrams or a power distribution chart. Then you unplug modules on the circuit until the draw goes away. .5A is too much, in general 50mA or less is an acceptable amount of draw.

Answer (score 2):

No. Your drain is not normal. 1.74 amps means 65 Ah battery will be flat in approximately 37 hours.

Also, 0.49 amps will mean 65 Ah battery will be flat in about 133 hours or 5.5 days. I wouldn't consider this acceptable either. On cars with smart key system, the drain can be relatively high for a while, for example on my 2016 Toyota RAV4 hybrid the system switches to power saving mode after 5 days, meaning there is slight delay, and after 14 days it switches to a mode saving even more power, meaning only the driver's door lock works. So, even on a smart key system, 0.49 amps is definitely too high drain as it won't last for much more than 5 days.

You seem to have two problems: firstly, the fuse you removed has some extra drain, and secondly, the 0.49 amps is anyway too high so you have some other extra drain as well. Keep removing the fuses and measuring the drain. Do note that if you have a door open, there may be a light on, so that could be your drain.

Answer (score 0):

Parasitic drain solved. Ok , had this on 3 Renault's . Very simple . The battery terminal connectors are rubbish . Disconnect . Clean everything , ( like in the old days ) reassemble , now here's the awkward part , push the connectors right onto the terminals properly . They need to be pushed all the way down, Renault seem to design these so it's near impossible to do in the dark or half light ..the connectors are the worst design ever . .
I had a massive parasitic drain and the poor old alternator was trying so hard to charge it was putting out 15.1v constantly all because the garage hadn't pushed the positive all the way down when reconnecting the battery .